# how to create a function for sum?

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, sum

Create  the C++ function    named   multiples   so  that    it  has three   parameters  sum,    x,  and n.
The first   two parameters  will    have    the type    represented by  the function    template    type
parameter.  n   will    always  be  int.        The return  type    is  void.       All parameters  are passed  by
value.  A function  created from    multiples   will    compute.
sum =   1   +   x   +   2x  +   3x  +   ... +   nx
and display the result  on  screen.

Comment: That looks a lot like a homework question. SO is not a homework machine. What have you tried?

Comment: @bhspencer It is ok to ask about homework as long as "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Comment: @GabrielOshiro which is why is down voted the question and asked the OP what they had tried. It is definitely not OK to just post a homework question verbatim and expect the community to answer it for you, which is what this user has done.

Comment: @bhspencer I know, I just wanted to clarify it because some people think it is forbidden to ask about homework here... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have an idea of loops and functions.

You have to use a loop here.

I guess this will work

```
void add(int n,int x,int sum)//as explained in the question  
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
       sum+=(i*x);//Adding x+2x+3x+....+nx
    }
}
```